# Automake: dependency on build result

Tags: linux, build, autotools, autoconf, automake

I use automake and autoconf.

In the subdirectory src/ the Makefile.am contains

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = hello.c
```

After building hello I want to run a tool (some analyzer/optimizer installed on the system) on the binary to modify it (e.g. strip) or generate statistics (e.g. dwarves, pahole ...). For this purpose the Makefile.am in the top-level-directory contains

```
tool:
         tool src/hello
```

When building hello with make and executing make tool everything is fine. The problem occurs when the user runs make tool without building the binary. How can I enforce building the bin_PROGRAMS (which may be a list) or just the hello binary as dependency of the target tool?

Neither

```
tool: bin_PROGRAMS
         tool src/hello
```

nor

```
tool: src/hello
         tool src/hello
```

work.

Comment: Can you post the makefile in its entirety?

Answer (score 1):

A Makefile target named 'tool' is supposed to *create* a file named 'tool'.  Since 'tool' already exists, Make assumes that it does not need to run the command again (I'm simplifying, but only a little).

A construct like this should work:

```
tool_output: tool src/hello
    tool src/hello > tool_output
```

Also, in general I believe you cannot use `bin_PROGRAMS` or any other Automake *variable* (assigned with `=`) as a *dependency*, but I could be wrong.

Comment: This is perhaps only personal style, but I don't think `.PHONY` / `FORCE` are meant to be used for this.  They're a defense against weird junk in your build directory, not a way to get around the normal semantics of makefile targets.

Comment: My question was on the dependency, not on the .PHONY problem. I am aware that the target tool must be a .PHONY target, as it doesn't create an output file in any case and some junk file may collide with its name. But in any case it needs the binary in the subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
tool: $(bin_PROGRAMS)
```

But you'll have the same problem as if you specify src/hello explicitly.  (Namely, the top level Makefile doesn't know how to build hello in src.)  You'd probably be better off doing something like:

```
tool:
        cd src && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) tool
```

in the top level and put the actual rule in src/Makefile.am, where you can list the dependency.  But that's a pretty bad idea, too.  Probably the best thing to do is use an all-local rule and put something like:

```
all-local:
        tool hello
```

in src/Makefile.am.  This will ensure that tool is run whenever you run make with no arguments, but it will not update the output when hello is rebuilt.  If that is acceptable, then this is a reasonable solution.  Another option is to do:

```
tool-output: hello
        tool hello
```

in src/Makefile.am and list tool-output in noinst_DATA in src/Makefile.am.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I think I will stick to the first solution and recurse into the subdirectory. The tools I need are optional and I only need the possibility to run them on purpose.